# Warping an image along a target mesh in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mesh

I am trying to warp an image of flat handwritten text (Which is generated using a neural network) along a target mesh (The lines of an image of binder paper) in Python. I am using OpenCV for image processing however I am fine using any means possible.

What I need to do:

1. Find the curved lines from the binder paper image. I already have a method to do this which I found from another Stack Overflow post, however it's not a great implementation and is very finickey. Best case scenario I have a list of points that represent each vertex of the line. However any implementation that finds the mesh works.
2. Apply the mesh to the text image so that the flat image becomes warped along the mesh of the paper lines.

The images I am using:
[Handwritten Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4I7F.jpg)
[Binder Paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRCMK.jpg)

What the result should look like:
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncocm.jpg)

- Notice how the text wraps along the curved edge of the paper?

How should I go about this? I have looked at libraries such as Skan however I haven't gotten the result I want. Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform